# curl dend notification to kaa server error

Tags: curl

This curl is not working for me to dend notification to kaa server...

```
curl -v -S -u devuser:devuser123 -F'notification={"applicationId":"32768","schemaId":"65546","topicId":"65538","type":"USER"};type=application/json' -F file=@notification.json "http://localhost:8080/kaaAdmin/rest/api/sendNotification" | python -mjson.tool
```

It is showing me the following error messages...

```
timeout on name lookup is not supported
```

... and...

```
Error 400 Required request part 'notification' is not present
```

Comment: * timeout on name lookup is not supported

Comment: I am getting: Error 400 Required request part 'notification' is not present.

Answer (score 0):

You need a space after the form field `notification`
The command should be as follows

```
curl -v -S -u devuser:devuser123 -F 'notification={"applicationId":"32768","schemaId":"65546","topicId":"65538","type":"USER"};type=application/json' -F file=@notification.json "http://localhost:8080/kaaAdmin/rest/api/sendNotification" | python -mjson.tool
```